# using multiple hiera.yaml files with puppet

Tags: puppet, hiera

after the introduction of Debian to our infrastructure as an OS for hardware as well as for VM's in our Ganeti environment, I am trying now to deploy apt sources lists for Debian hosts by using a local `hiera.yaml` file within the module it self.

We are deploying the apt sources lists for Ubuntu as well as our local repo with a dedicated module as a wrapper for puppetlabs/apt module. The global `hiera.yaml` on puppet server looks as follows:

```
---
version: 5
defaults:
  datadir: data
  data_hash: yaml_data
hierarchy:
  - name: "module scope"
    paths:
      - "%{facts.fqdn}.yaml"
      - "%{facts.context}-%{facts.location}-%{facts.hostgroup}.yaml"
      - "%{facts.context}-%{facts.datacenter}-%{facts.hostgroup}.yaml"
      - "%{facts.context}-%{facts.hostgroup}.yaml"
      - "%{facts.context}-%{facts.location}.yaml"
      - "%{facts.context}-%{facts.datacenter}.yaml"
      - "%{facts.context}.yaml"
      - common.yaml
    datadir: "/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/%{environment}/modules/%{module_name}/data"
```

In the `apt_sources` module the `common.yaml` contains the apt key of our repo. The `%{facts.context}.yaml` contains all Ubuntu and our repo sources lists, which is sufficient in most cases, thus for some host groups we need some external repos, such as `mysql`, `percona`, `ceph` etc.. and these sources are included in the respective yaml file, either in a `%{facts.context}-%{facts.hostgroup}.yaml` or on of the other yaml files and at the end we just merge the hashes in `%{facts.context}.yaml` and in the other relevant yaml files.
Now with Debian things are getting a bit more complex, I had to restructure the `data` directory in our `apt_sources` module so Debian sources lists are separated from Ubuntu sources lists as follows:

```
apt_sources$ tree -L 1 data/
data/
├── common.yaml
├── Debian
└── Ubuntu

2 directories, 1 file
apt_sources$
```

and I created a local `hiera.yaml` file with the following content:

```
---
version: 5
defaults:
  datadir: data
  data_hash: yaml_data
hierarchy:
  - name: "module scope"
    paths:
      - "%{facts.operatingsystem}/%{facts.fqdn}.yaml"
      - "%{facts.operatingsystem}/%{facts.context}-%{facts.location}-%{facts.hostgroup}.yaml"
      - "%{facts.operatingsystem}/%{facts.context}-%{facts.datacenter}-%{facts.hostgroup}.yaml"
      - "%{facts.operatingsystem}/%{facts.context}-%{facts.hostgroup}.yaml"
      - "%{facts.operatingsystem}/%{facts.context}-%{facts.location}.yaml"
      - "%{facts.operatingsystem}/%{facts.context}-%{facts.datacenter}.yaml"
      - "%{facts.operatingsystem}/%{facts.context}.yaml"
      - common.yaml
    datadir: "/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/%{environment}/modules/%{module_name}/data"
```

The relevant part of our `init.pp` which has to stay puppet 3 compatible due compatibility to some QA infrastructure:

```
#
class apt_sources (
  Hash $gnupg_key     = {},
  Hash $pin           = {},
  $proxy              = {},
  $purge_sources      = false,
  Hash $settings      = {},
  Hash $sources       = {},
  ) {

  class { 'apt':
    update => {
      frequency => 'daily',
    },
    purge  => {
      'sources.list'   => $purge_sources,
      'sources.list.d' => $purge_sources,
    },
  }

  create_resources('apt::source', hiera_hash('apt_sources::sources', $sources))
  create_resources('apt::setting', hiera_hash('apt_sources::settings', $settings))
  create_resources('apt::key', hiera_hash('apt_sources::gnupg_key', $gnupg_key))
  create_resources('apt::pin', hiera_hash('apt_sources::pin', $pin))

  Apt::Pin <| |> -> Apt::Source <| |> -> Apt::Ppa <| |> -> Exec['apt_update'] -> Package <| |>
}
```

Now when deploying the apt_sources for a host with an additional `%{facts.context}-%{facts.hostgroup}.yaml` file, the sources lists are not getting merged, rather only the more specific yaml file wins, in this case the `%{facts.context}-%{facts.hostgroup}.yaml` file, so the main repos in `%{facts.context}.yaml` are not deployed.
In puppetserver I can see in the logfile how Puppet looks up for the keys using the global `hiera.yaml` and then the local `hiera.yaml` but only for the first hash, then there is this line:

```
Hiera configuration recreated due to change of scope variables used in interpolation expressions
```

and Puppet keeps looking for the other keys, but this time using only the global `hiera.yaml` configuration and skips the local one so Puppet cannot find any hash and using the default `{}` value.

Unfortunately I cannot replace `hiear_hash` with `lookup` function for the moment due Puppet 3 compatibility.

**EDIT**

Originally with only Ubuntu as OS I had all hiera data in the directory `data/` and the `init.pp` looked like this:

```
#
class apt_sources (
  $proxy         = {},
  $purge_sources = false,
  $merge_sources = true,
  ) {

  class { 'apt':
    update => {
      frequency => 'daily',
    },
    purge  => {
      'sources.list'   => $purge_sources,
      'sources.list.d' => $purge_sources,
    },
  }

  if $merge_sources {
    $sources = hiera_hash('apt_sources::sources', {})
    create_resources('apt::source', $sources)
  }
  else {
    $sources = hiera('apt_sources::sources')
    create_resources('apt::source', $sources)
  }

  $settings = hiera_hash('apt_sources::settings', {})
  create_resources('apt::setting', $settings)

  $gnupg_key = hiera_hash('apt_sources::gnupg_key', {})
  create_resources('apt::key', $gnupg_key)

  $pin = hiera_hash('apt_sources::pin', {})
  create_resources('apt::pin', $pin)

  Apt::Pin <| |> -> Apt::Source <| |> -> Apt::Ppa <| |> -> Exec['apt_update'] -> Package <| |>
}
```

Maybe someone can explain this behavior.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by adding the following to the `common.yaml`:

```
lookup_options:
  apt_sources::sources:
    merge:
      strategy: deep
```

further more I changed the `create_resources` statements as follows:

```
create_resources('apt::source', $sources)
create_resources('apt::setting', $settings)
create_resources('apt::key', $gnupg_key)
create_resources('apt::pin', $pin)
```

Comment: @John Bollinger Hi John, I hope you can explain this behavior. I never had to add the merge lookup options to a yaml file. Is it maybe because of the second `hiera.yaml` of the module and the nested directories for the hiera data?